# Single word for "Needs Improvement"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a review/moderation system for content submissions. Each submission may have one of the following statuses:

1. **Submitted**, pending review/moderation. Action: `submit()` triggered by the User when submitting, events fired: `submitting`, `submitted`.
2. **Needs Improvement**, I use this status to tell the user that his submission needs a correction/revision before it can be approved. Action: `needsImprovement()` triggered by Me, events fired: `needingImprovement`, `neededImprovement`.
3. **Improved**, the user has submitted a correction/revision as requested. Action: `improve()` triggered by the User, events fired: `improving`, `improved`.
4. **Approved**. Action: `approve()` triggered by the Me, events fired: `approving` , `approved`.
5. **Rejected**. Action: `reject()` triggered by the Me, events fired: `rejecting`, `rejected`.

Can someone please let me know if there is a single word that can be used to replace **Needs Improvement** status?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is *Needs Improvement* of a different form than the others? As suggested in the other comment, if you don't have *Needs Approval*, *Needs Publishing*, or *Needs Rejection*, why are you using *Needs Improvement* in the first place? It should follow the same form as the others, and just be *Improved*.

Comment: @JasonBassford Beacuse when I reviewing user's submission and when I feel that his submission is nearly mets all criterias, I don't want to just reject it because once a submission rejected the system will automatically delete it from database. Instead, I want to tell the user that his submission is "Needs some improvements" before it can be approved and mark it with a unique status. I just can't find a proper term for it, that's why I posted this question here.

Comment: @JEL Thank you! Actually, the `improve()` action is already exists, it's called when the user submitting a revision for his submission that currently has "Needs Improvement" status, once a revision submitted the status will be revert back to "Submitted" so it can be included in pending review list.

Comment: I don't get it. You say you already have `improve()` and are mapping it to *Needs Improvement* to the user. As the first comment says, why can't you just called the fired events `Improving` and `Improved`?

Comment: If you need some kind of status *prior* to all of this, before something is even looked at, you could use *Proposed*.

Comment: What is the action which takes an item from  `needingImprovement` to `neededImprovement`?

Comment: @JasonBassford When I call `needsImprovement()` action that's mean I'm asking the user to improve his submission while `improve()` action is called by the user to telling me that he has submitted a revision.

Comment: @RobinBetts read my comment above.

Comment: `revising` and `revised`?... given it would only ever be revised if it needed improvement?

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, a submission can only be revised if the current status is Needs Improvement. However, I'm using the terms `improve`,  `improving`,  `improved` instead of `revising`,  `revised`.

Comment: R.e. your comment immediately above this, if you're already using those terms for that situation then what's the issue? I think it's impossible to understand what's going on here from the descriptions given in these comments. I keep mentally going in circles and coming back to the same original confusion. Is the problem perhaps that you're trying to distinguish an *original* submission from *subsequent* submissions? (If so, does that mean that if somebody updates or improves—or whatever you want to call it—something a *second* time that you'll be looking for a third set of names?

Comment: I would consider updating your question with a flowchart of the situation, listing all of of the current possible steps and scenarios.

Comment: @JasonBassford I've updated the question with an explanation on the statuses.

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm thinking to use "Soft Rejected", the action would be `softReject()`, and events: `softRejecting`, `softRejected` but it still two-words. I need a single word.

Comment: Assuming you provide some commentary to indicate how the submission should be improved, you could say it has been "annotated".

Comment: Surely the name of the called action is invisible to the user and the words you use to communicate with the user (whether in messages or on screen) are just labels or blocks of text. You already have a single word for the action name, you called it "needsimprovement". What you display to the user is irrelevant so you can go with "Needs Improvement"

Comment: I'm sorry so many of you guys fell for this, and the Question is not about English, nor anything like English.

As you specified above, you are defining your own language, which has to do with English only what you can justify.

Can you justify anything, or should we just ignore all of this?

Comment: Of course there's a single word for that;  "improvable" but how is that useful?

Submitted; Needs Improvement; Improved; Approved; Rejected are your personal, arbitrary choices, are they not?

Is there a way you see any of that relating to English, or any other language, or must we rely on your arbitrary and unsupported choices?

Comment: Naming of classes and variables is **explicitly off-topic**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the help pages explicitly define its subject matter as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want a past tense verb as well here in order to describe the completed salient activity.

*Reviewed* might work for you, or alternatively *screened* if you wanted to keep the review for the final stage which results in either approval or rejection.

Answer (score 1):

**Deficient** -- the state of containing one or more deficiencies.

If a submission is found to be deficient, then it will not be approved until those deficiencies are amended.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions are:

- Inadequate - meaning that the submission doesn't meet the requirements or it is insufficient for its purpose;
- Incomplete - meaning that the submission doesn't have all the parts necessary for its approval;
- Unsatisfactory - meaning that the submission isn't good enough (as simple as that)

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Apart from the fact that you have answered an off-topic question, we do expect answers here to **explain** themselves. A list of words with no explanation of how they are relevant is not a good answer.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for your comment; being a new user, I have yet to understand which questions are regarded as "off-topic", but I agree that my original comment wasn't informative enough, so I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the question is the false assumption that steps 2. and 3. need to be completely separate processes.

By making them separate, it leads to some confusion and redundancy.

I suggest the following:

> 2 a) **Needs Improvement**, I use this status to tell the user that his submission needs a correction/revision before it can be approved. Action: `improve()` triggered by Me, event fired: `improving`.
>
> 2 b) **Improved**, the user has submitted a correction/revision as requested. Action: `improve()` triggered by the User, event fired: `improved`.

Both you and the user trigger the *same* action `improve()`.  If *you* trigger the action, then the `improving` event is fired and the status is set to *Needs Improvement*. If *the user* triggers the action, then the `improved` event is fired and the status is set to *Improved*.

Depending on who triggers the action `improve()`, the system fires the appropriate event.

This also allows for you to look at an improvement and determine if it needs *further* improvement, thereby allowing multiple iterations until something is finally approved (or possibly rejected).

---

**Note**: If changing the code to accommodate this simpler status-based flow isn't an option, I still recommend only presenting two status messages to the user: *Needs Improvement* and *Improved*. (With a possible interim *Improving*.) One represents that they need to work on something, the other that they've already worked on it and returned it for further review.

Regardless of what you name the functions and events in the code—or what *you* see when looking at the interface—having synonyms for *needs improvement*, *improved*, or even *rejected* (as with the *soft-rejected* idea from a comment) at the same time as the original will result in users become puzzled and perhaps complaining about the extra words and status messages.

---

If there must be an extra status message shown to the user, I suggest **Under Review** (`review()`, `reviewing`, `reviewed`). It's neutral, without the somewhat negative connotation of *Soft-Rejection* that's been mentioned in comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my system the `ing` event is fired before the system change the status and `ed` event fired after the status has been changed. For example, when `approve()` action is called, there is a piece of code that listens for `approving` event, it checks whether someone who triggered the action has permission to do that or not if it returns `false`stop and cancel the action, if it returns `true` the continue the process, set the status to *Approved*, once status changed then the system will fire `approved` event and there is another piece of code listen to it.

Comment: Combining *Needs Improvement* and *Improved* status will lead to more confusion in my system, for example when querying submissions that already improved by the user and querying submissions that still waiting to be improved. I this case, I have to refactor my codebase completely which I'm trying to avoid. Let's don't talk about how my system works, I just need a single word recommendation for **Needs Improvement** if there is any, if no then I will stick to it or use **Soft-rejected**.

Comment: @Rifki I've updated my answer. You can use whatever naming you want for the extra step inside the code itself, but I think its simpler for the user, and won't present any confusion, if *they* only see two status messages: *needs improvement* and *improved*. The code itself can do different things, and you can see different things, but I wouldn't present those extra steps to the user.

Comment: @Rifki **Note**: If you *are* going with something like *Soft-Rejected*, and you *do* show it to the user, I would pick *Soft-Approved* instead, just so that it has a positive feel to it rather than a negative one. Or, alternatively, *Under Review*, which doesn't rely on referring to any particular final decision.

Answer (score 0):

"Lacking." A tad judgy, but I think it fits the bill. Or "incomplete" if you want to be more literal and neutral.

Answer (score 0):

**Revise**

> Examine and make corrections or alterations to (written or printed
>   matter)
>   [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/revise)

Rather than a state (e.g. rejected) an action to be taken by the submitter before any further action can be taken by the system. You would likely need another state, **Resubmitted**.

Answer (score 0):

> **Challenged**: The submitted content has been challenged by the reviewer and needs to be defended or improved to overcome the challenge and get accepted, or it will be rejected.
>
> **Criticized**: The submitted content has been criticized by the reviewer and needs to be improved to incorporate the criticism.
>
> **Suspended**: The submitted content has been deferred / postponed by the reviewer and needs to be improved before the suspension is lifted.